# Как автоматически запустить программу при новом включении компьютера?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

я пишу программу которая автоматически при в включении компьютера запустит одно приложения,но я не могу найти код который запустит эту программу.Пожайлуста помогите

код

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Games\StarCraft II\StarCraft II"])
```

Comment: *не могу найти код который запустит эту программу.* Поищите в планировщике.

Comment: @Akina Вероятно стоит уточнить для ТС, какой *Планировщик* вы имеете в виду и как в нем искать.

Comment: У меня win7, поэтому буду говорить как у нее. В меню пуск есть папка Startup, у нее путь `C:\Users\<имя юзера>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` то, что в ней находится будет запущено при запуске ОС. Там у меня есть несколько скриптов на питоне. Чтобы питон скрипт был запущен, нужно указывать интерпретатор питона, например через батник/cmd или через ярлык винды

Comment: @gil9red *то, что в ней находится будет запущено при запуске ОС* Сказки. То, что находится в указанной папке, будет запущено при запуске сеанса пользователя. Каковое может произойти несколько раз на один запуск компа, а может и не произойти ни разу.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за замечание, не знал (у меня все-таки один пользователь) :)

Comment: @Kromster Боюсь, что тогда следующей темой будет "не могу войти в компьютер"...

Comment: @gil9red у меня этот метод, увы, работает не со всеми программами/скриптами. Некоторые запускаются, некоторые упорно игнорируются. P.S. на борту Win10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Проверенно на Windows 8

```
import winreg

# Добавить в автозагрузку 
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
winreg.SetValueEx(key, "Date Time", 0, winreg.REG_SZ,"C:\\Program Files\\Date Time\\Date Time.exe")
key.Close()

# Удалить из авто загрузки
# key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
# winreg.DeleteValue(key, "Date Time")
# key.Close()
```

Инструкция:

- Пишите путь к программе как показано в примере
- запускаете скрипт, открываете диспетчер задач
- смотрите авто загрузка, там должно появится ваше приложение
- перезагружаете компьютер и радуетесь)

Comment: А как выглядело бы "отключение" этого автозапуска?

Comment: gil9red Поправил ответ)

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение к ответу :D