# Почему программа не прописывается в автозапуск?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите понять, почему программа не прописывается в автозапуск.

```
import time
import os
import getpass

USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()


def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
    if file_path == "":
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
    with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
        bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)
while True:
    os.startfile(r'r.png')
    time.sleep(4)
```

Нижняя часть с `while`'ом работает, а вот верхняя часть - нет. Так что прога не прописывается в автозагрузку. Прошу помочь начинающей прогерше.

Comment: Чтобы функция сработала, её надо вызвать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870859/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/870971#870971